# Adding java compiler flags to everything but protocol buffers in android gradle project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, protocol-buffers

I have a an Android project that uses protocol buffers. I would like to turn on -Werror and lint checks, so I've added this to my app's build.gradle:

```
android {
// snip
      tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.addAll("-Xlint:all", "-Werror"])
    }
}
```

I also have a protobuf block:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
    }


    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want my own code to treat warnings as errors, but not generated protobuf code (which lands in app/build/generated/...). How can I only give the flags to my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the easiest way to do this is to have a subproject for the protobuf artifacts and to only apply compilation flags to the consumer of that library.